# Как извлечь нужные данные с html страниц?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

на сервере по адресу:

```
http://generator:91
```

находится html страница.
Как можно запросить или достать оттуда нужные мне данные из тегов таблицы:

```
<tr><td>Длинна</td><td>16</td></tr>
<tr><td>Пароль</td><td>Jnsrfnm0@6Jnjrvz</td></tr>
<tr><td>Перевод</td><td>Отыкать0@6Отокмя</td></tr>
```

чтобы можно было работать с ними на клиенте с помощью js или html:
если конкретнее то мне нужны строки:

```
Jnsrfnm0@6Jnjrvz и Отыкать0@6Отокмя
```

Comment: Смотрите вопросы "парсинг страниц". Так вы хотите что б клиент парсил или сервер? Если сервер - то ваш вопрос по php и метка javascript не нужна. Если клиент- то наоборот.

Comment: И укажите, проблема получить текст страницы, или проблема распарсить текст?

Comment: На самом деле это очень комплексный вопрос и ответ зависит от многих параметров. Например, вы хотите отправлять запрос из фронта? Если да то находится ли эта страница в вашем домене? Если нет то разрешены ли на нее корс запросы? Если нет то можно ли разрешить? Если нет то придется ее дергать из сервера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP

```
$str = "<tr><td>Длинна</td><td>16</td></tr>
<tr><td>Пароль</td><td>Jnsrfnm0@6Jnjrvz</td></tr>
<tr><td>Перевод</td><td>Отыкать0@6Отокмя</td></tr>";

preg_match_all("#(\w+)@(\w+)#imu", $str, $match);

var_dump($match[0]);
// array(2) { [0]=> string(16) "Jnsrfnm0@6Jnjrvz" [1]=> string(29) "Отыкать0@6Отокмя" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

`<tr><td>Длинна</td><td id="long" >16</td></tr>
<script>
    var $long= document.getElementById('long').innerHTML
<script>`

Указываете id html элемента, и достаете содержимое тега через  javascript